# Logs appending each time on its own when refreshing the logged in page

Tags: files, logs, syslog

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     21837 Jun 14 15:56 access_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    163101 Jun 14 14:17 access_log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    472757 Jun 10 07:05 access_log.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    163775 Jun  1 16:08 access_log.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    826435 May 26 08:17 access_log.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     14972 Jun 14 15:56 error_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     41249 Jun 14 14:17 error_log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    698331 Jun 11 04:02 error_log.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    191310 Jun  4 04:02 error_log.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 179420763 May 28 04:02 error_log.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 May  5 04:02 ssl_access_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       850 May  4 15:45 ssl_access_log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      1948 Apr 26 16:29 ssl_access_log.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        73 Feb  7 17:46 ssl_access_log.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       219 Feb  4 10:12 ssl_access_log.4`
Does anyone know how to stop access log files and error log files in httpd to stop from appending each time whenever I have logged in and refresh that logged in web page.The size of the logs are increasing each time

Comment: Do you have log rotation in place? Most packages will apply it. It should mean you don't have to worry about the size of log files (unless you are getting so many logged messages that relatively recent messages are rotated out).

Comment: How to check if log rotation is running or not if not then how to activate log rotation

Comment: "The size of the logs are increasing for no reason." isn't true or helpful - the logs are increasing because there is logging taking place - can you delete this sentence?

Comment: That formatting needs cleaning up (move it to the end, use initial spaces not backticks). And explaining - this makes no sense to a new visitor. You should add the logrotate config from one of your comments here, as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the `error.log` file grows it means that there's some error the httpd server is encountering when you load that webpage. You should check the log and fix what's wrong.

Concerning `access.log` growing, well, that's what it's supposed to do when you visit the webpage.

Edit: as pointed out by @JoeP, you should also activate log rotation (via `logrotate`) so that older logs are gzipped/deleted.

Comment: How to check if log rotation is running or not if not then how to activate log rotation

Comment: @XanderCage I added an answer re log rotation

Answer (score 0):

**Log rotation** should be used for this. Most distros have `logrotate` running daily (at least) and many packages add their logs to the logrotate configuration.

Taking `error.log` as an example, if you see files in the same directory like

- `error.log.1`
- `error.log.2.gz`
- `error.log.3.gz`

then log rotation is already running. The current file is still `error.log`,  first rotation is `error.log.1`, and later rotations are compressed to save space.

To check `logrotate` is running look for a script `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` - this tells `cron` to run `logrotate` daily. (You can do it hourly to if you want. Some distros have a different path, see link below.)

To check `logrotate` is rotating a specific log, look for config files in `/etc/logrotate.d/`. If httpd logs aren't there, look at one of the existing files for an example or study `man logrotate`.

More info: [Understanding logrotate utility](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/understanding-logrotate-utility/)

(Log rotation isn't the complete answer if you have so many messages that one day's or one hour's output is unmanageable.)

Comment: httpd file is there in /etc/logrotate.d/ directory and it has /var/log/httpd/*log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /sbin/service httpd reload > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}   inside this file

Comment: But why is it still increasing the size of the logs if log roatation is running

Comment: Do you mean it has been running for several days getting bigger?

Comment: Yes it has been running for several days and each time I refresh the logged in webpage the size gets bigger and bigger...first time it was this 

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     12556 Jun 14 15:48 error_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     20349 Jun 14 15:48 access_log   then I refreshed it the size of access and error log changed to 

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     14972 Jun 14 15:56 error_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     21837 Jun 14 15:56 access_log

Comment: In which directory? Are they really `error_log` not `error.log`? (That wouldn't affect it, it's just very odd.) Are there no `error.log.1` files?

Comment: In my opinion those are not very big!

Comment: In /var/log/httpd directory.They are error_log not error.log.There are error_log.1,error_log.2 files available in this directory

Comment: Can you add the file list and sizes to the original question? Since formatting lines isn't possible in comments. `ls -l /var/log/httpd` - include all of it unless there are > 20 files

Comment: Its done..You can check it

Comment: Please format it - look at the help

Comment: Its done You can check it